# Curl Get Specific value from the output

Tags: json, linux, loops, curl, awk

I have one curl command if I run it , output as below,

```
{
  "page" : 1,
  "records" : 1,
  "total" : 1,
  "rows" : [ {
    "automated" : true,
    "collectionProtocol" : "MagBead Standard Seq v2",
    "comments" : "",
    "copy" : false,
    "createdBy" : "stest",
    "custom1" : "User Defined Field 1=",
    "custom2" : "User Defined Field 2=",
    "custom3" : "User Defined Field 3=",
    "custom4" : "User Defined Field 4=",
    "custom5" : "User Defined Field 5=",
    "custom6" : "User Defined Field 6=",
    "description" : null,
    "editable" : false,
    "expanded" : false,
    "groupName" : "99111",
    "groupNames" : [ "all" ],
    "inputCount" : 1,
    "instrumentId" : 1,
    "instrumentName" : "42223",
    "jobId" : 11111,
    "jobStatus" : "In Progress",
    "leaf" : true,
    "modifiedBy" : null,
    "name" : "Copy_of_Test_Running2"
  } ]
}
```

I want to extract only jobId`s value.
This output will be

```
  11111
```

If there is multiple rows then, there is multiple jobId

```
  11111
  11112
  11113
```

I want to extract only jobId and process in the while loop.
like below,

```
 while read job; do
 echo $job
 done < < (curl command)
```

and I want to use that job id in another command.
That curl results could be multiple.

Do you have idea to get easy to extract curl output and make a while or for loop?

Comment: use jq: http://stedolan.github.io/jq/

Comment: What is the format if there is multiple rows ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think `jq` (thanks to @Mircea ) is a nice solution.

Besides, I can provide a simple `awk` solution only if the curl's output format is disciplinary and does not has any dirty symbol.

So, just be careful to use this:

```
while IFS= read -r line
do
    echo $line|awk -F':' '/jobId/{split($2,a,",");for(i in a){if(a[i]){printf("%d\n",a[i])}}}'
done < "$file"
```

Comment: Thank you I think jq is awesome I don't need to make awk